# awk length is counting +1

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying, as an exercise, to output how many words exist in the dictionary for each possible length.
Here is my code:

```
$ awk '{print length}' dico.txt | sort -nr | uniq -c
```

Here is the output:

```
...
1799 5
427 4
81 3
1 2
```

My problem is that awk length count one more letter for each word in my file. The right output should have been:

```
1799 4
427 3
81 2
1 1
```

I checked my file and it does not contain any space after the word:

```
ABAISSA
ABAISSABLE
ABAISSABLES
ABAISSAI
...
```

So I guess awk is counting the newline as a character, despite the fact it is not supposed to.
Is there any solution? Or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Also, try to show the output of `cat -vet dico.txt`: sometimes, weird characters are there and are difficult to track.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean sorry. But you can download the dico.txt here if it is what you want : http://www.siteduzero.com/uploads/fr/ftp/mateo21/cpp/dico.zip

Comment: What I mean is that the question should be self contained, so you should provide a meaningful example of the file with which we can "play" and reproduce the error, in order to help you find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm gonna venture a guess. Isn't your `awk` expecting "U*X" style newlines (LF), but your dico.txt has Windows style (CR+LF). That easily give you the +1 on all lengths.

---

I took your four words:

```
$ cat dico.txt 
ABAISSA
ABAISSABLE
ABAISSABLES
ABAISSAI
```

And ran your line:

```
$ awk '{print length}' dico.txt | sort -nr | uniq -c
      1 11
      1 10
      1 8
      1 7
```

So far so good. Now the same, but dico.txt with windows newlines:

```
$ cat dico.txt  | todos > dico_win.txt 
$ awk '{print length}' dico_win.txt | sort -nr | uniq -c
      1 12
      1 11
      1 9
      1 8
```

Comment: And now, you've uploaded the file... Indeed the guess was correct.

Comment: Your guess was right. It was exactly the problem. So i just put my file through dos2unix to solve it.
Thanks !!